# How to make a http request from a Chrome extension to an api

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm doing some tests with a Chrome extension and I can't make a simple get request to my API. My API returns a json and when the extension receives the response, it should console log it.

In my manifest.json I have this permission:

```
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/"
  ],
```

And in my background.js I have this

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https//localhost:5001/api/values", true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log(xhr);
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

When this code gets executed I get this message in the browser's Console windows
`GET chrome-extension://cajbfgbekfaohncbcejeobaamefgfebd/https//localhost:5001/api/values net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

My guess is that the request includes `chrome-extension://cajbfgbekfaohncbcejeobaamefgfebd` and this is what's causing the issue. But even if that's the case I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You have a typo: missing `:` in the URL.

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I missed that! Thank you @wOxxOm

Answer (score 0):

Yep nothing special here, the problem was a typo as @wOxxOm pointed out.